# Different result of product of all numbers in a list with Numpy and using a for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numbers:

```
numbers = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
```

I want to print the product of all the numbers in the list (all multiplied together).
I did this with Numpy:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.product(numbers))
```

and using a for loop:

```
total = 1
for number in numbers:
    total *= number
print(total)
```

Why does the first (with Numpy) output 1137766400 and the second (with the for loop) 1074879590400? Shouldn't I get the same output? I don't understand the difference, what is the correct product?

I've tried formatting my code in a different way (numpy.prod(), total = total * number), but that (of course) gives the same outputs.

Comment: These two approaches should indeed be giving the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is 1,074,879,590,400. You are getting a different result from `numpy` because you are supplying it integers and you are getting integer overflow. Python integers, on the other hand, do not overflow. Change your list to

```
numbers = [12., 10., 32., 3., 66., 17., 42., 99., 20.]
```

and you will see that both techniques give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting integer overflow, try specifying the dtype manually; i.e.

```
import numpy as np

numbers = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]

total = 1
its = 0

for number in numbers:
    total *= number
    its +=1

print(f'After {its} iterations total is {total}, numpy product is {np.prod(numbers,dtype=np.int64)} numpy version {np.version.version}')
```